# Rearrange string into 2D array python

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following string after using urllib:

```
459,2277,617459268\n14619,99,19600737\n11297,99,18666551\n16603,99,19761406\n12660,99,28741324\n4543
```

after using replace and split:

```
data = data.replace('\\n', ',').split(',')

['459', '2277', '617459268', '14619', '99', '19600737', '11297', '99', '18666551', '16603', '99', '19761406', '12660', '99', '28741324', '4543']
```

However, I had like to get the following 2D array:

```
459 2277 617459268
14619 99 19600737
11297 99 18666551...
```

Is there a way to break this 1D array into a 2D array without using `numpy`?

When I say 2D array I mean column list when each row is 1x3 list.

Easy ways will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: if `\n` is not line break - `[x.split(',')  for x in data.replace('\n', "\n").split()]`

Comment: it worked how ever I needed to change it into: data = [x.split(',') for x in data.replace('\\n', "\n").split()]. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't replace your "row delimiters" by "column delimiters". Instead, for split the string on the row delimiter. Then split each row on the column delimiter.

If your input has new line characters:

```
rows = data.split()
```

If your input has a literal backslash followed by the letter `n` rather than a newline character:

```
rows = data.split('\\n')
```

Either way, now you can split each row on commas:

```
matrix = [row.split(',') for row in rows]
```

Comment: then I get something like: [['459', '2277', '617459268\\n14619', '99', '19600737\\n11297', '99', '18666551\\n16603', '99', '19761406\\n12660', '99', '28741324\\n4543', '99', '29451763\\n445',

Comment: @Ben Where does your input come from? Does it have new line characters or a backslash followed by an en?

Answer (score 0):

save this str to string like s then :

```
s='''459,2277,617459268\n14619,99,19600737\n11297,99,18666551\n16603,99,19761406\n12660,99,28741324\n4543'''

for i in s.split('\n'):
    print (i)


459,2277,617459268
14619,99,19600737
11297,99,18666551
16603,99,19761406
12660,99,28741324
4543
```

or if you want to print without `,` :

```
for i in s.replace(',' , ' ').split('\n'):
    print (i)


459 2277 617459268
14619 99 19600737
11297 99 18666551
16603 99 19761406
12660 99 28741324
4543
```